# Свойство pk моделей

Tags: python, django

Объясните для чего нужно свойство pk у моделей. Допустим, есть строка кода: `current_rubric = Rubric.objects.get(pk=rubrik_id)`. Я понимаю, что в переменную `current_rubric` добавляется первый найденный объект, значение поля которого равно `rubric_id`, но почему используется именно свойство pk? Во время работы в shell при использовании этого свойства экземпляра (nameEx.pk) возвращается просто число, в чем смысл?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: думал будет легче

Comment: трудно на тренировке - легко в бою =)